# Did Salesforce remove FLS visibility for HasOptedOutOfEmail and HasOptedOutOfFax during a release update automatically?

Tags: apex, fls, release, data-protection-and-privacy

I'm pretty sure my code was querying these some time ago inside a dynamic SOQL query. Today I can't query them anymore because FLS seems to be removed from the Admin profile that I'm using.

Easy solution: just turn FLS on. But that is not what I'm looking for.

If my assumption is true and Salesforce did remove the FLS during an release update: Why is Salesforce removing FLS?

I think this could be related to the new function *Data Protection and Privacy* found here in the classic-setup /ui/setup/individual/ConsentManagementEnabledPage?setupid=ConsentManagement

IMO Salesforce should NOT do that, because custom code might break.